# URL title required - channel form

Tags: safecracker

Any idea why if i have french characters for name et first name (First letter only) i got :URL title is required error?

If name or first name start  with ÉÀÖ etc..
My channel form contain .. dynamic_title='{current_time format="%Y%m%d%H"}-[last_name]_[first_name]-[date_de_naissance]'   ( at first i put last_name and first_name at the beginning then i tried like this (time in first position).. but still no luck!

EDIT :
After few tests the problem occur with any capital letter anywhere in the word, not only the first letter..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marked as : bug accepted on github... 
https://github.com/ExpressionEngine/ExpressionEngine/issues/315

Comment: Can you add a link to the bug when you get a chance? Might help users in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Good idea!  I edited my post

Comment: Awesome, thanks. You can also "accept" your own answer here, too.